# How to excract data from edited datatable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I want to creat an shiny app where users have to edit datatable.
There is the code contains reproductible exemple:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
 
 
line<-c(1,1,1,1,1)
op<-c(155,155,155,156,156)
batch<-c(1,2,3,1,2)
voile<-c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
depot<-c(2,NA,2,NA,NA)
 
boe<-data.frame(line,op,batch)
 
ui <- fluidPage(
   
    # Application title
    titlePanel("test dust"),
   
    actionButton("refresh", label = "refresh"),
   
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
   
    actionButton("save", label = "save"),
 
)
 
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   
    DTdust<- eventReactive(input$refresh, {
        DTdust <-data.frame(line,op,batch,voile,depot)
    })
   
    merged<-reactive({
        merged<-merge(boe,DTdust(),all.x = TRUE)
        })
   
    mergedfiltred<-reactive({
        mergedfiltred<- filter(merged(),is.na(voile)|is.na(depot) )
    })
   
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable( mergedfiltred(),editable = list(target = 'cell',
    disable = list(columns = c(1:3))),selection = 'none'
    )                                                                          
}
 
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I wish this works like this —>

When user clic on refresh button. Dtdust.csv (here simulated) is read , then it merged with boe.csv (simulated too) an filter to get only rows without resulta for voile and depot col.
And display this merged filtred ino editable datatable .

This part works.

After i want to extract the data from edited datatable to make some processing on it (extract rows completed, rbind it on dtdust and save as dtdust.csv. But that’s ok i think.)
I’ m in trouble to extract edited datatable.
I see some exemple to do it with classic dataframe but it not work with reactive one.

I’m beeginner so if you can comment a lot your answers i can learn how to and not just ctrl+c ctrl+v your code :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `reactiveValues` data frame.  Then you need to update it via `observeEvent` whenever any cell is modified via `mytable_cell_edit`. The updated dataframe is now available in the server side, and part of it is now printed in the second table. You can use `DF1$data` for further analysis or subsetting.  Full updated code is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

line<-c(1,1,1,1,1)
op<-c(155,155,155,156,156)
batch<-c(1,2,3,1,2)
voile<-c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
depot<-c(2,NA,2,NA,NA)

boe<-data.frame(line,op,batch)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("test dust"),
  
  actionButton("refresh", label = "refresh"),
  
  DTOutput("mytable"), DTOutput("tb2"),
  
  actionButton("save", label = "save"),
  
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  DTdust<- eventReactive(input$refresh, {
    req(input$refresh)
    DTdust <-data.frame(line,op,batch,voile,depot)
  })
  
  merged<-reactive({
    req(DTdust())
    merged<-merge(boe,DTdust(),all.x = TRUE)
  })
  
  mergedfiltred<-reactive({
    mergedfiltred <- filter(merged(),is.na(voile)|is.na(depot) )
    DF1$data <- mergedfiltred
    mergedfiltred
  })
  
  output$mytable = renderDT( 
    mergedfiltred(),
    editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(1:3))), selection = 'none'
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$mytable_cell_edit, {
    info = input$mytable_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col  
    v = info$value
    
    DF1$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, DF1$data[i, j])
  })
  
  output$tb2 <- renderDT({
    df2 <- DF1$data[,2:5]
    plen <- nrow(df2)
    datatable(df2, class = 'cell-border stripe',
              options = list(dom = 't', pageLength = plen, initComplete = JS(
                "function(settings, json) {",
                "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
                "}")))
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks for your solution @YBS.
I finaly find a solution by myself half an hour after asking here... (i previously turning arround hours and hours).
There is what i do :

```
    output$x2 = DT::renderDataTable({
        req(dat$x2)
        DT::datatable(dat$x2)
    })
    dat <- reactiveValues()
   
    # update edited data
    observeEvent(input$mytable_cell_edit, {
        data_table <- dat$x2
        data_table[input$mytable_cell_edit$row, input$mytable_cell_edit$col] <- as.numeric(input$mytable_cell_edit$value)
        dat$x2 <- data_table
    })
```

Have a good day